# How does Adore-Ng rootkit gets loaded into the kernel

Tags: security, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am working on detecting kernel level rootkits and have chosen Adore-Ng as my first test rootkit. After having known how this rootkit hides itself and other processes in the Linux kernel (2.4, 2.6 versions), I now want to know how it gets loaded into the kernel.

Specifically, I want to know whether

**1. It calls any already existing APIs in the Linux kernel** OR

**2. Does it have any hard-coded assembly instructions such that as soon as its compiled, it gets loaded into the kernel?**

I went through the source code of Adore-Ng but couldn't find anything in this direction and could only see how it achieves its goal of hiding.

Can anyone tell/suggest how I can find its loading behaviour?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The core of the Adore rootkit is a malicious module, so for it to be loaded into the kernel you first need root access, then run insmod (or modinfo).
Another way to load Adore is to infect a trusted kernel module as described in Phrack volume 0x0b, issue 0x3d. It wouldn't be as stealthy as the former way because the cleaner module wouldn't be invoked. Since you went through the source code, I believe you have the aptitude to modify the source to invoke the cleaner module once the Adore module has infected a legit module. (make sure you also leave no trace of the module infection; the cleaner will not pick that up).
Any admin worth his salt would use signed modules, so don't expect these methods to work on production kernels after the 2.6 mainline.